# Jupyter Notebook Not lunching

Tags: jupyter

after I install Anaconda navigator, I tried to Lunch Jupyter notebook for my project, It display a CMD for a while and it disappear, then I recieve the following error, pls I will need your help on this.
C:\user\name\AppData\Roaming\jupeter\runtime\nbser-4484-open.html
 paint cannot read this file this is not a valid bitmap file

Comment: Try running Anaconda navigator as administrator.

Comment: If you use firefox, try this: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4500

Comment: I have tried to run the anaconda navigator as administrator,  yet I keep receiving the same error C:\user\name\AppData\Roaming\jupeter\runtime\nbser-4484-open.html paint cannot read this file this is not a valid bitmap file